# Come out of my days

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He immediately knocked me back, I fell backwords onto my butt and it took
>   me a few seconds to kinda **come out of my days**.

What does "come out of my days" mean?

Comment: Dis you read this or hear it? If you heard it, the word was probably _daze_.

Comment: It was most likely "daze" not "days", pronounced the same. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/daze?q=daze

Comment: @KateBunting I heard it in a video. "daze" makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JayA.Little Thank you Jay!

Comment: @Moha You may wish to note that the word said is spelled "backwards". There are other words that end in "-wards", indicating direction of movement, like "forwards", "upwards", etc.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Days' and 'daze' are homophones: the sound the same but have different meanings. They can be difficult for non-native speakers when heard, but rarely cause the same confusion in writing.

You've obviously found out that the actual meaning was "unable to think or react properly, or bewildered," not "units of time lasting 24 hours."

Below is a link that will explain homophones in detail as well as other confusing words that can have:

- The same sound with:

  - Different spellings
  - Different meanings
- The same spelling with:

  - Different meanings
  - Different sounds

It's no wonder we need an English Language Learner's site!

[HOMONYMS, HOMOPHONES,
HOMOGRAPHS, and HETERONYMS](http://www.magickeys.com/books/riddles/words.html)